# Are processes not created on all nodes?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

when I distribute my application across a number of nodes and create processes in each, processes are separate to all nodes they are created on.

Is this the case with distribution? are processes not replicated across nodes?

If I have a Long running process representing a real life machine, say I have to init this process at start up, what happens when the system goes down do I have to re initialise it?

Comment: Some parts of your question are too vague to address. For example, what does "system" mean?

Answer (score 2):

When spawning a process in Erlang it is up to you to decide, possibly implicitly, where it is spawned. The default choice is the node of the process that executes the `spawn` call.

There is no 'replication', unless you explicitly add it.

Comment: I can sort of see the problem with spawning processes on 2 nodes, how would you handle long running processes?  By just re-entering the data into the system to spawn them again when a node crashes? Or trying to spawn them on separate nodes

Comment: That depends entirely on your application. Some applications are fine with just starting up a new process and rebuilding some state. Some applications have to replicate the state to other processes, possibly on other nodes. But because the need is different in different scenarios, Erlang can not make this choice for you.